# Wrong results when converting binary strings to decimal

Tags: php

I have written the following function to convert an IP address in binary format to decimal dotted notation:

```
function bin_to_ddn($binary_ip) #converts a binary IP in DDN
{
    $binary_ip_arr = str_split($binary_ip,8); #convert binary IP to array
    foreach($binary_ip_arr as &$value) { #convert each octet to decimal
        $value = bindec($value);
    }
    $ddn = implode('.',$binary_ip_arr); #convert to string
    return $ddn;
}
```

The problem is that this function works for some numbers and not for others. For example:

```
11000111000000010000000101100000
```

becomes

```
199.1.1.96
```

But

```
11000111000000010000000101111111
```

becomes

```
199.1.1.127.0
```

For some reason, it's adding an extra octet at the end. Any idea what might be wrong in this function?

Comment: if the final output contains 5 elements, then `$binary_ip_arr`  contains 5 elements. Are you sure there are no leading or trailing spaces in `$binary_ip`?

Comment: (Also I just tested your code and the output I get is `199.1.1.127` for `echo bin_to_ddn("11000111000000010000000101111111");`)

Comment: Way to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @AbraCadaver oh well, one can't know them all. It can catch them all though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that your string contains trailing spaces. Consider the following tests:

```
echo bin_to_ddn("11000111000000010000000101111111 ");
>>> 199.1.1.127.0

echo bin_to_ddn("11000111000000010000000101111111");
>>> 199.1.1.127
```

I recommend trimming the input:

```
$binary_ip_arr = str_split(trim($binary_ip),8);
```

If this is user generated input, you may want to add more input validation.

Answer (score 1):

just implemented your code - works perfect, but did some modifications, maybe it could help somehow:

```
function bin_to_ddn($binary_ip) #converts a binary IP in DDN
{
    $binary_ip_arr = str_split($binary_ip,8); #convert binary IP to array
    $dec_arr = array();
    foreach($binary_ip_arr as $value) { #convert each octet to decimal
        $dec_arr[] = bindec($value);
    }
    $ddn = implode('.',$dec_arr); #convert to string
    return $ddn;
}

echo bin_to_ddn('11000111000000010000000101100000');

echo bin_to_ddn('11000111000000010000000101111111');
```

Comment: Hey thanks. What kind of improvement would this bring over my code?

Comment: when you use some tricks like `&$value` and `$value = bindec($value);` it is not very clear for me. I am trying to avoid if possible this `&$`  so finally you had some spaces in your string?

Answer (score 0):

There are built-in functions to do these operations:

```
echo long2ip(bindec('11000111000000010000000101111111'));
```

Or in the function:

```
function bin_to_ddn($binary_ip) #converts a binary IP in DDN
{
    return long2ip(bindec((string)$binary_ip));
}
```